# How to create an igraph object from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I'm using a dictionary to represent a graph in my Python program. I'm using the keys of the dictionary to represent vertices and the values to represent the adjacent nodes of each vertex. The dictionary currently looks like this:

```
{  
   'v1' : ['v2','v3'],
   'v2' : ['v1'],
   'v3' : ['v1','v4'],
   'v4' : ['v3']
    // And so on. 
}
```

Is there a straightforward way to create a new [igraph object](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/index.html)  from this dictionary? If there's no easy way, what's the next-best option?

Comment: How does igraph format look like? Is there a lib for python?

Comment: @pajton: Check the `python-igraph` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, according to the [docs](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/index.html), it seems that `igraph` expects `vertices` encoded as `integers`. So you need to specify a `mapping` from your `vertices` to `integers` and then you could actually proceed for example like this:

```
G= {'v1': ['v2', 'v3'], 'v2': ['v1'], 'v3': ['v1', 'v4'], 'v4': ['v3']}
mvi= {'v1': 1, 'v2': 2, 'v3': 3, 'v4': 4}
graph= igraph.Graph(edges= [(mvi[v], mvi[a]) for v in G.keys() for a in G[v]])
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense. it's a large dataset so i might need to write another script to create the mapping dictionary.

Comment: You could build `mvi` using `enumerate`.

Comment: ah never heard of enumerate, i was thinking of putting all my vertices into an array and then using .index instead of using a dict.  that may be a better way to go though

Comment: A fairly hidden part of the ``igraph`` library is the ``UniqueIdGenerator`` class which allows you to generate unique integer indices for strings (or any other hashable objects). ``UniqueIdGenerator`` is a drop-in replacement for your mapping dict ``mvi`` which will build the mapping on-the-fly. See http://packages.python.org/python-igraph/igraph.datatypes.UniqueIdGenerator-class.html

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this which imports names of vertices to the graph also:

```
relations = {'v1': ['v2','v3'], 'v2': ['v1'], 'v3': ['v1','v4']}
g = igraph.Graph()
g.add_vertices(list(set(list(relations.keys()) + list([a for v in relations.values() for a in v]))))
g.add_edges([(v, a) for v in relations.keys() for a in relations[v]])
```